# taking real or imaginary part makes array not C-contigous in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy-array and I need it to be C- of F-contiguous (for `paraview`):

`t=np.linspace(0,10)
y=exp(1j*t)`

So far it is contiguous, which I check by `y.flags`.
But when I take either real or imaginary part of this array - it becomes non-contiguous, for example `y.real.flags` shows that. If I on the other hand take `abs(y)` or `angle(y)` - they are both contiguous, so I can actually find real and imaginary part by doing `cos` or `sin` of `angle(y)`. Why is taking `real` or `imag` make array non-contiguous? Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y.real` and `y.imag` are just giving you views into the `y` array that skip every other 8 bytes. Notice that `OWNDATA: False` flag? That's what it means: they're just a view onto someone else's data. That's also why they're not contiguous. It's not a bug, it's an optimization.

`abs` and `angle` have to build a whole new array. Which is contiguous, but it also means you just spent linear time and space instead of a constant few dozen bytes and nanoseconds.

Of course if *want* to build a whole new array, you can always do that explicitly:

```
>>> y.real.copy().flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Or:

```
>>> np.ascontiguousarray(y.real).flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

`copy` of course always copies; I believe `ascontiguousarray` copies only if the array isn't already contiguous. That doesn't seem to be guaranteed [in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html), but I'm pretty sure it just calls [`require`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.require.html#numpy.require). (Anyway, either one will be a lot faster than `cos(angle(y))`.)

Comment: Thanks, for me at the moment this optimization is very strange and unintuitive as all other (?) mappings with functions are contiguous. Maybe I'll understand it later though.

Comment: @Sleepyhead It's an optimization because it doesn't have to copy the array. This makes a huge difference for large arrays—instead of allocating space for 1 million new rows and looping and copying over 1 million new values, it just makes a new tiny array handle that points to the existing 1 million rows in memory, with a striding flag that means "skip every other 8 bytes"